# Excel worksheet in c# array date Issues

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have created a program which converts an Excel worksheet into a text file. I load the whole of the worksheet into an array then loop through it and write out the columns I need. Some of the columns are dates.

My issues are some dates are e.g. `06/09/2014` but are being output as `09/06/2014`. I have formatted the dates using `CultureInfo("en-GB")` when I read it from the array. Is this not the right way?

Comment: show us your code that you are using to format your date and how you are saving them to your text file

Comment: Perhaps the same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355790/date-conversion-issue-with-excel-interop-and-csv-file

Comment: Are you sure that your excel file uses correct British date format? Even if you set the cell correctly in C# , the excel file may still use its own format.